Before-trigger flow: why can't you use a formula field from a related record?
I'm trying to build a flow to update a particular record, triggered by that record being updated. I'm looking to use a before-save flow (optimized for fast field updates).
One of the formulae in the flow wants to use a formula field from a related record (which isn't changing) to calculate a value, but this is not allowed - no formula field at all is supported in a before-save flow.

I understand why I can't use a formula field from the record being updated in such a flow, but I can't see a reason why we can't use a formula field from a related record which is not being updated. Is there a genuine reason not to allow this?
IF({!$Record.Role__r.FTE_Ratio__c} = 0,
  0,
  {!AnnualSalary} / {!$Record.Role__r.FTE_Ratio__c})

In the above example, FTE Ratio is a formula field on the related Role record.
Does anyone have any good options to get around this? I can think of 3, but none seem ideal:

Use {!$Record__Prior.Role__r.FTE_Ratio__c}, but if I've just re-linked this record to a different Role, it will take the old Role's FTE Ratio, which is wrong - I don't mind the old value from the Role record (that hasn't changed), but I do need it from the correct Role.
Re-build the formula in my flow. This will work, but introduces duplication and maintenance issues
Run a query within the flow to fetch the value of FTE Ratio from the related Role record. This will also work, but adds a query and some extra complexity that I'd rather save.


Please [edit] your post to clarify the specific error or problem you're having when you try to use the field.  You should be able to reference a related record's formula field in your flow.

@DavidCheng that is a good point. Edited to include a screenshot of the error. Basically, you can't save the flow because formula fields are not supported at all in a before-save flow.

Related records are not automatically available. If you want to use a field from a related record you have to use a get records action. In your case you would use it to get the Role with as filter Id equals $Record.Role__c.
 Then you can user the record from the get action in your formula with Get_Role.FTE_Ratio__c

Does this not consume an extra SOQL query in the transaction? Perhaps not a huge issue, but we have run into plenty of SOQL limits in the past and I'm trying to be mindful of not wasting our governor limits...
